# create independent copy by initializing list with list in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Will the following end in two independent lists in Java?

```
List<Obj> list1 = getList();
List<Obj> list2 = new ArrayList<Obj>(list1);
```

At this point are list1 and list2 independent of each other?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it out? Anyway, the answer is yes. Just beware that you can still modify the contained elements if they're mutable and the changes will be seen in both lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "independent of each other"? The variables `list1` and `list2` will hold different references, but the content will be same, meaning that the references to which the `List` refer will be the same in both list objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy will contain the same **references** to the objects of the source list, since you only copy the references, a shallow copy.

So you can alter the list, as in removing or adding elements without changing the source list.

If you however alter an element of the list, the changes will show up in both lists, the source and the copy.

Answer (score 1):

No, the two lists aren't fully independent of each other.  Creating another `ArrayList` will work, but it will refer to the same items as the original list.  You have created a shallow copy.

The new list is a separate list, but modifying an object in one list will be visible in the other list.

To create a fully independent list, you will want to create a *deep* copy of the list, which involves duplicating each of the objects in the list also.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Obj> list1 = getList();
List<Obj> list2 = new ArrayList<Obj>(list1);
```

Since you used the keyword `new`, `list1` is absolutely not equal to `list2`. In other words, they are two different lists. However, they share the same list of elements (i.e., these elements have the same references). See the [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) of ArrayList for details.

If you want to make a completely independent list from the original, you might need to do a deep copy. For example,

```
List<Obj> list1 = getList();
List<Obj> list2 = new ArrayList<Obj>();
for (Obj obj: list1) {
  list2.add(obj.clone());
}
```

Note: `clone` only makes a shallow copy of the object.